# how to change infoWindow Style in react-google-maps reactjs

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I want to change the style of infowindow:
creat a CSS file to change `.gm-style .gm-style-iw-d` and `.gm-style .gm-style-iw-c` proprty but nothing to chnage , i wnat to change or disable `max-width` ,`over-flow:scroll` , `padding-right`,... like this pic :[image] 
and i read this link: [InfoWindowOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindowOptions) and write this line for change `maxWidth` :
`<InfoWindow options={{maxWidth:300}} onCloseClick={() => togelOpenCloseInfoWindos}>`
but nothing to change.
and this is my code:

```
 {isOpen &&
                            <InfoWindow options={{ maxWidth: 300 }} style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }} onCloseClick={() => togelOpenCloseInfoWindos}>
                                <Grid container style={{ paddingLeft: 8, paddingRight: 8, }} xs={12} spacing={0} >
                                    <Grid item xs={7} sm={8} zeroMinWidth>
                                        <Typography noWrap component="p">
                                            <Box fontWeight="bold">
                                                {props.MyProps.locations.NICKNAME}</Box>
                                        </Typography>
                                        {/* <p className={classes.card_title}>{car.NICKNAME}</p> */}
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid item xs={5}>{speed_logo(props.MyProps.locations)}</Grid>
                                    <Grid item xs={7} style={{ marginTop: -9 }}><p className={classes.card_time}>{timeToShow(props.MyProps.locations.SENTDATE)}</p></Grid>
                                    <Grid item xs={5} style={{ marginTop: -9 }}>{tempture_logo(props.MyProps.locations)}</Grid>
                                    <Grid xs={12}><Typography component='p' className={classes.card_Address}>{props.MyProps.locations.POSDESCRIPTION}</Typography></Grid> </Grid>
                            </InfoWindow>
                        }
```

please help me to change style of infoWindow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how to change your InfoWindow via `element.style{}` in the CSS file however I successfully override these values when I put it inside the `.gm-style .gm-style-iw-c {}` on the CSS file and appending `!important` on each line, like the following [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-simple-map-wuz5m9?file=style.css):

```
.gm-style .gm-style-iw-c {
   padding-right: 10px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
    max-width: 500px !important;
    max-height: 326px !important;
    min-width: 0px !important;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%,-100%);
    background-color: #dd9191;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

*Note: This might be what you are looking for, however it is possible that class names will be changed by Google Maps Platform in the future.*

As for the maxWidth options in the InfoWindow, I tried using it in my reactjs code without overriding it in my CSS file and it worked properly. Here is how it looks like in my [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-simple-map-zjn2ml?file=index.js):

```
<InfoWindow onCloseClick={this.props.handleCloseCall} options= {{maxWidth : 100 }}>
                 <span>This is InfoWindow message!</span>
             </InfoWindow>
```

*Note: You need to change the `YOUR_API_KEY_HERE` string with your own API key in the index.js of the code provided for it to work properly.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is prone to failure as these class names, as well as any other class name output by the API are **undocumented**. Do not use this solution.